# CakePHP update on form change

Tags: php, cakephp

This form :

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->select('quantity', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], ['value'=> $this->Number->format($cartitem['quantity']) ,
        'class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'number']);
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

is inside a view. I want to make it so when a user selects a new quantity value, it calls the updateQuantity function inside the cartController.

```
public function updateQuantity($prod_id)
{
    //get query for product and user (need for using composite key)
    $query = $this->Cart->find('all')
        ->where(['users_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'product_id' => $prod_id])
        ->contain([])
        ->limit(1);

    $data = $query->toArray();
    $data[0]['quantity'] = $this->request->getParam('quantity');

    if ($this->Cart->save($this->makeEntityFromArray($data[0]))) {
        $this->Flash->info(__('The item has been updated.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->info(__('item update fail. Please, try again.'));
}

return $this->redirect($this->referer());
```

I'll probably just refresh the page to update for now. So i want to call that method when another item in the drop down is chosen. How?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with page reloading, just point your form to your action:

```
$this->Form->create(null,["url" => ["controller" => "Cart", "action" => "updateQuantity"], "id" => "my-form"]);
```

Also change these lines, if you want to submit your form via POST:

```
$data[0]['quantity'] = $this->request->getParam('quantity');
```

to:

```
$data[0]['quantity'] = $this->request->getData('quanitity');
```

Or, if you want to submit your form via GET, just add another option to your Form->create(): `"type" => "get"`

You need also a way to submit this form. As you want to submit it on input value change, you need to use some JavaScript. Example using jQuery:

```
$("#my-select").change(function(){
    $("#my-form").submit();
});
```

If you do not want to reload page, you can just call your action with, eg. $.ajax().

Comment: this does in fact submit the form and refresh the page, though the actual value just changes to 0 each time. It's not passing through the value from the form to post....

Comment: I checked your code once again, and updated my answer.